# Where are the values of the Dropdown list I made in a custom module in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sql, sugarcrm, dropdownlistfor

I've created a Module which contains a Dropdown list and I would like to modify the list's items (especially I need to get them from the database with SQL).
Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/custom/include/language/en_us.lang.php or whichever language code you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the include folder in the custom folder... Maybe somewhere else I could find it?

Comment: One will be created there when you go to Admin->Dropdown Editor and edit the dropdowns or when you deploy/install your module.